# How to instantiate ViewModelFactory in Activity

Tags: android-studio, android-room, viewmodel

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME HOW TO INSTATIATE VIEWMODELFACTORY IN ACTIVITY

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME HOW TO INSTATIATE VIEWMODELFACTORY IN ACTIVITY

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val viewModelFactory = DiaryViewModelFactory(diaryDao)
       val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DiaryViewModel::class.java)
```

**VIEWMODELFACTORY**

```
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(DiaryViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return DiaryViewModel(diaryDao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

**APPLICATION CLASS**

```
    val database : DiaryDatabase by lazy {
        DiaryDatabase.getDatabase(this)
    }
}
```

**DAO CLASS**

```
interface DiaryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from diary WHERE id = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Entry>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(entry: Entry)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(entry: Entry)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(entry: Entry)

    @Query("SELECT * from diary ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Entry>>
}
```

Comment: Please don't shout at people on SO.  If you are getting an error, what that error is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally instantiated viewModelFactory like this

```
 val viewModel: DiaryViewModel by viewModels{
        DiaryViewModel.DiaryViewModelFactory((application as DiaryApplication).database.diaryDao())
    }
```